# Animated PNG frame rate in p5js

Tags: p5.js

I tried an animated PNG with p5 and it seems to work:

https://editor.p5js.org/dirkk0/sketches/q4Y5HzOYC

Is there a way to control the frame rate?

Answer (score 2):

P5 has a `frameRate()` [function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate) but this changes the framerate of the canvas not of your gif, so I assume you don't want that.

I think it would be a good idea to take a look at the [p5.play](https://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/) library - it has a tonne of functionality you could use, including a loadAnimation() which takes in your gif and creates an animation object - whose frame rate you can change by using `animation.frameDelay`.

So your example - with the p5.play library - would look like this:

```
var anim;
var sprite;

function preload() {
  // loads all the image files
  anim = loadAnimation('test.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);

  // change how many frames (of draw loop) each animation frame is
  // visible for. bigger #s = slower speed
  anim.frameDelay = 2;

  // create a sprite from a single image
  sprite = createSprite(300, 150);
  sprite.addAnimation("test", anim);
}

function draw() { 
  background(220);
  drawSprites();
}
```

here's a really good example https://editor.p5js.org/kjhollen/sketches/BJ1a_DIkM

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this code/lib has several issues:

a) it doesn't work with animated PNGs.

b) p5.play wasn't updated for a long time, which possibly leads to
c) if you import p5.play with the latest p5, the console tells me that something got overwritten, also GIFs are also broken (your sketch works with p5.js from 2017)
d) the author claims that it is beta and not very performant
From a quick look into the issues I learned that it
e) only works in global mode which is another show stopper for me.

But as I understand it, there is no solution in p5 itself, then.

Comment: @dirkk0 Every figure this out?

Comment: @user3500371 nope.